# What is the difference between JAVA date format "dd/MM/yyyy" and "dd/mm/yyyy"?

Tags: java, sql-server, date, datetime

While writing a code for a java project I used date format *"dd/mm/yyyy"*. But another colleague writing code for the same project used *"dd/MM/yyyy"* format and mismatch occurred. I also observed that database date format works fine with *"dd/MM/yyyy"*, not with *"dd/mm/yyyy"*.
So I need to know the difference between these two formats.

Comment: mm is for minutes. Like we have HH for Hours in 24 hours format and hh for Hours in 12 hours format.

Answer (score 3):

The difference can be found here https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

basically small m is minute bit M is month